# Create a Sub account deploy contract and initialise it, via RPC with NEAR Protocol

Tags: nearprotocol

I am developing the front end part of a project, with the NEAR protocol and react, where the work flow I am looking for is:

1. User logs in.
2. Creates a subaccount and deploys a contract to the sub account.
3. Then we initialise the contract so they can interact with it.

I have working code to add the sub account and deploy. But I am getting errors when I try to call the initialise function of the contract. This is the code I have so far.

```js
const createSubaccount = async () => {
    let subaccount;
    let formattedStr = formatStr(collection.name) + "." + account.accountId;
    console.log("Formatted string is: ", formattedStr);
    try {
      let data = await fetch("../../assets/main.wasm");
      let buf = await data.arrayBuffer();

      console.log(account.createAndDeployContract);

      subaccount = await account.createAndDeployContract(
        formattedStr,
        "ed25519:7VoAvGkKCtyBTCBaiydVySyGnbqNw4vz2nwDpdSXgzER",
        new Uint8Array(buf),
        "37100000000000000000000"
      );
      console.log(
        "New sub account is created and contract deployed to it : ",
        subaccount
      );
      //const res = await deployContract(subaccount, formattedStr);

      
      //return subaccount;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Sub account creation failed: ", error, subaccount);
    }
    // try {
    //   let call = await account.functionCall({contractId: "sqwd.drawstringjoby.testnet",methodName: 'new_default_meta',args:{ owner_id: 'sqwd.drawstringjoby.testnet' }, gas: GAS })
    //   console.log('called contracted init : ', call)
    // }catch (err){
    //   console.log("error initilsing the contract: ", err)
    // }

  };

  const init = async (owner_id) => {
    /*********************** The focus is initializing the contract to point to the new created subaccount *******************************/

    let formattedStr = formatStr(collection.name) + "." + account.accountId;

    const contract = await new nearAPI.Contract(
      wallet.account(),
      formattedStr,
      {
        viewMethods: [],
        changeMethods: ["nft_mint", "new", "new_default_meta"],
        sender: wallet.getAccountId(),
      }
    );
    try {
      return await contract.new_default_meta({ owner_id: "fghjhg.drawstringjoby.testnet" }, GAS);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
```

The error I get when I try to call the final try is as follows:

```
Error: Error happened while deserializing the module
    at Object.parseResultError (rpc_errors.js:31:1)
    at ConnectedWalletAccount.signAndSendTransactionV2 (account.js:160:1)
    at async ConnectedWalletAccount._signAndSendTransaction (wallet-account.js:227:1)
    at async Contract._changeMethod (contract.js:102:1)
    at async init (index.jsx:90:1)
```

Any ideas on the piece of the puzzle I am missing?

Comment: Is it possible to post the relevant contract code as well? My first guess is that you need to use @nearBingden annotation on your contract classes (if the contract is AssemblyScript.)

Comment: @John the contract is in Rust, and follows the NFT standards for NEAR

Comment: Could you see if you're able to call the `new_default_meta` using the near-cli (if that is the final try you are referring to?) I can't see any problem with the front-end code, and suspect that the error is in the contract code.

Comment: @John, in the CLI it works fine, I can deploy and call all the functions in the contract